# What can i use to get insect/bug remains off my vehicle?

Tags: cleaning

I recently went on a 10000k road trip, and accumulated a lot of insect remains on my vehicle.  After several car washes, one of them that even included a bug spray before you entered the main wash, and doing some hand washing, there is still insect gunk on my vehicle!  It's mostly on the bumper, the windshield was much easier to clean.

What is the best product or method to use then removing insect gunk from a car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few methods, but remember, that if the bugs have been there for a while, the acidic content of the bugs might just have ruined the paint.

1. Use a light scouring pad, like a “000” steel wool, to slowly and carefully shave off layers of the bug.
2. Spray WD 40 on the bug, let sit for 10 to 15 minutes, then wash off with soapy water and a cloth. Remember not to use this method on glass.
3. Scrub Coca Cola on the bug with a cloth, let sit 30 seconds, then scrub off with a dry cloth. For safety of the paint, use soapy water and a cloth to wash the Coca Cola off.
4. Dip a dryer sheet / fabric softener sheet in water and wipe the bug off with the sheet.
5. Same method as #4, but drop a dryer sheet / fabric softener sheet in warm water in a spray bottle (about a quarter full), spray on the bug and use another dryer sheet to wipe the bug off.
6. Mr. Clean Magic Eraser Sponge

If all else fails, maybe it's time for a single edge razor and a new paint job :( pesky bugs are pesky.

Comment: Woah woah woah, a Magic Eraser is a fine sandpaper, this should *not* be used on a vehicle's paint. Several companies make Bug and Tar remover specifically for dissolving bug guts and making it easy to blast off with water pressure or a light rub of a microfibre cloth.

Comment: Maybe also suggest a cloth dampened with hot water and leave it covering the bugs, the wetness and heat can perform miracles in dislodging welded on bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I have had very good luck with the type of  kitchen sponge/scrubber made for teflon pans. It is wrapped in a nylon mesh that takes off bugs and pinesap but is gentle on the paint. Spray or wipe on any Bug and Tar remover from the auto parts store. Do small area at a time. Let it sit for 10-15 minutes in the shade before scrubbing. Rinse the sponge often to keep from smearing it around.

Comment: Here in the UK they sell a bug and tar remover sponge which as per their description states it is covered with some sort of abrasive fabric. Here is an image of it https://images.lteplatform.com/images/products/600x600/549771641.jpg?v=1. I own one and have used it to some success of removing what looks like stubborn tree sap from my cars windshield. May be worth a go with some sort of cleaning product as others have stated.